# how to add new field & value from selected joined table

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js

i have a joined table like this

[image]

i want to create new field named `qty_exceed` and the value is based from

(`qty_stock` - `qty_taken`)

do i have to do it in the query or make separate operation and store it in a varible?

my code

```
$getmaterial = ContractProduct::select(
        'product_item.ref_rof_id',
        'product_item.code',
        'product_item.qty_stock',
        'contract_product.qty_taken'
    )
    ->where('ref_rof_id', $getrof->ref_rof_id)
    ->join('product_item', 'contract_product.ref_product_id', '=', 'product_item.code')
    ->get();

    $data['getquoid'] = $getquoid;
    $data['getmaterial'] = $getmaterial;
    $view = $this->module_path . '.next-create';
    
    return response()->view($view, $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DB::raw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions)

But remember, raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.

With `DB::raw` your code will look like this:

```
$getmaterial = ContractProduct::select(
        'product_item.ref_rof_id',
        'product_item.code',
        'product_item.qty_stock',
        'contract_product.qty_taken',
         ContractProduct::raw('product_item.qty_stock - contract_product.qty_taken as qty_exceed') 
    )
    ->where('ref_rof_id', $getrof->ref_rof_id)
    ->join('product_item', 'contract_product.ref_product_id', '=', 'product_item.code')
    ->get();

    $data['getquoid'] = $getquoid;
    $data['getmaterial'] = $getmaterial;
    $view = $this->module_path . '.next-create';
    
    return response()->view($view, $data);
```

Comment: i tried to put dd($getmaterial) right under get() but getting an error : stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: nvw, i just need to change ContractProduct::raw into \DB::raw